# Homogenizing a collection

Tags: java, generics, subclass

Suppose I have a non-generic `List` or a `List<Foo>`, for which you know that all of the elements are of type `Bar`, which is a subclass of `Foo` (which will always be the case).  Assume that you cannot alter the code that gets you the original list so that you can get a `List<Bar>` directly.  Is there some library or some other thing that assists in "homogenizing" this list?

That is, is there a function in the vein of

```
public static <T, U extends T> List<U> homogenize(List<T> list, Class<U> subclass);
```

that I can use somewhere?  (`homogenize()` returns a view of the input list, with functions that take in `U` rather than `T` or `Object` where appropriate.  It does not return a copy of the list.  If the input list cannot be homogenized - that is, if not all elements are of type assignable to U, then `homogenize()` returns null.)

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a library, my first thought was to use [Google Guava Libraries](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) as follows:

```
public <T, U extends T> List<U> homogenize(List<T> list, final Class<U> subclass) {
    Predicate<T> pred = new Predicate<T>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(T input) {
            return input.getClass().isAssignableFrom(subclass);
        }
    };
    return Iterables.all(list, pred) ? (List<U>)list : null;
}
```

I didn't try it out yet to make sure the kinks are out.  However, I looked at it, and decided it was pretty butt-ugly.  SLightly better Guava approach is:

```
public <T, U extends T> List<U> homogenize(List<T> list, Class<U> subclass) {
    Iterable<U> ret = Iterables.filter(list, subclass);
    if (list.size() != Lists.newArrayList(ret).size()) return null;
    return (List<U>)list;
}
```

However, it's still a bit ugly.  And it uses an internal copy of the collection.  It does still return a cast view of the original.  After all is said and done, the cleanest approach seems to use regular Java:

```
public <T, U extends T> List<U> homogenize(List<T> list, Class<U> subclass) {
    for( T t : list) {
        if (!t.getClass().isAssignableFrom(subclass)) return null;
    }
    return (List<U>)list;
}
```

Depending on your aversion to typecast warnings, you could even drop the cast operators in all three options.

**EDITS PER COMMENTS**
The following changes/improvements were suggested in the comments.

Option one improved:

```
public <T, U extends T> List<U> homogenize(List<T> list, final Class<U> subclass) {
    return Iterables.all(list, Predicates.instanceOf(subclass)) ? (List<U>)list : null;
}
```

Option two improved:

```
public <T, U extends T> List<U> homogenize(List<T> list, Class<U> subclass) {
    Iterable<U> ret = Iterables.filter(list, subclass);
    return (list.size() != Iterables.size(ret)) ? null : (List<U>)list;
}
```

Option three improved:

```
public <T, U extends T> List<U> homogenize(List<T> list, Class<U> subclass) {
    for( T t : list) {
        if (!subclass.isInstance(t.getClass())) return null;
    }
    return (List<U>)list;
}
```

With these improvements the 1st Guava example shines quite a bit.  If you don't mind static imports, both Guava examples become extremely readable.

Comment: Instead of using isAssignableFrom, couldn't you just cast each element and catch the ClassCastException to return null?

Comment: This will only help you in compile time. In run-time, it might fail.

Comment: @KevinWelker: you have your `isAssignable()` calls backwards, but more simply you can do `subclass.isInstance(input)`, or even more simply use Guava's `Predicates.instanceOf(subclass)`. And in the second approch, you can use `Iterables.size()` instead of creating a copy. But once you use `Predicates.instanceOf()`, I think the first one is quite clear. Whether you prefer it or the purely imperative approach is a question of taste :-)

Comment: @FrankPavageau, I thought subclass.isIntance(parentClass) was the inverse of parentClass.isAssignableFrom(subclass), so I thought what I showed is identical -- although admittedly isInstance is easier to understand.  I'll make the suggested changes, thanks.

Comment: In the above, I meant "inverted form" rather than "inverse".

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just cast it?

```
public static <U> List<U> homogenize(List<? super U> list){
    return (List<U>)list;
}
```

Note that generics are a purely compile time check. If the types are not what you expect, you will get an exception when you try to cast an object which isn't a `bar` to a `bar`.

Edit: I didn't notice that you want it to actually check the type of the contents and return null on failure. If you don't know for sure that the items are the right type and want failfast behavior, you're better off with one of the other approaches.